# Remove SWIGTYPE from Generated Class name

Tags: swig

Is there anyway to remove the SWIGTYPE part from the generated class names and replace with another string literal?

i.e. change SWIGTYPE_p_ex_session.java to ex_session.java (strip off generated "SWIGTYPE_p_")

SWIG .i file:

```
%module Example
%{
#include "ExampleApi.h"
struct ex_session{};
%}

%include "ExampleApi.h"
```

ExampleApi.h contains the below:

```
typedef struct ex_session session_t;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the real issue here is the "ugly name" then I'd solve this one by making sure SWIG has at least an empty definition (not just a declaration) visible when it's generating the wrapper, for example given:

```
%module test

class ExampleNiceName;

typedef ExampleNiceName example_t;

void func(example_t);
```

SWIG generates `SWIGTYPE_p_ExampleNiceName.java`

We can make this a whole lot better just by doing something like:

```
class ExampleNiceName {};
```

instead of

```
class ExampleNiceName;
```

in this example, which causes SWIG to generate `ExampleNiceName.java` as a wrapped type instead. It doesn't expose anything more than previously exposed and is perfectly legal/sane. We're telling SWIG not just "this type exists", but "this type exists and we'd like you to wrap nothing beyond it's name" by doing this.

You can also use `%rename` to make the name on the Java side different from the C++ class name, for example:

```
%rename(JavaClassName) ExampleNiceName;
class ExampleNiceName {};
```

with the previous example would cause `JavaClassName` to be used in place of `ExampleNiceName` in the generated Java.

Comment: I was trying to use your suggestion to modify my SWIG Interface file but I'm unable to do so.  I've added a rough outline of my SWIG Interface file above now, any idea on how to remove the "SWIGTYPE_p_" from SWIGTYPE_p_ex_session_t.java?

Comment: @c12 - the `typedef` isn't what renames it at all, it's the visibility of a deifition. I *think* for your particular case you'd want to add `struct ex_session {};` in your SWIG interface file (i.e. the .i one), almost anywhere other than in the `%{` at the top.

Comment: shouldn't I be declaring the instance of ex_session (sess_t)...its the one that gets renamed to SWIGTYPE_p_sess_t.java.  I renamed it a bit to make it more clear.   I've tried adding struct ex_session {}; and struct sess_t {}; but both throw a compile exception of "wapi_wrap.c:1388: error: invalid application of `sizeof' to incomplete type `ex_session'"

Comment: @c12 - `struct ex_session {};` is almost certainly right from SWIG's perspective - you need to do it for the type that things are once all the `typedef`s have been resolved. Since that's an error from the generated C file it sounds like there's no definition of that `struct` visible on the C side - you want to add `%{ #include "myheader.h" %} to the top of the SWIG interface to fix that, where myheader.h provides that definition.

Comment: thanks for the response awoodland.  I've really simplified my .i and  have included it above as is.  I still get the SWIGTYPE_p_ex_session.java file name even if I include the struct ex_session{}; right after the include of the ExampleApi.h.  Any more ideas?