# How to rename SWIGTYPE_p... to something more friendly?

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have a c++ function returning an uint8_t* array like:

```
uint8_t* getData();
```

Swig maps this to a SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char. I would like a more friendly name. In my .i file I have simply included my h file containing the code above. I have tried %rename but it doesnt work:

```
%rename (SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char) u8_t;
%include "myhfile.h"
```

How do I force Swig to rename my type (or solve it some other way)?

Comment: I'm fairly sure renaming isn't what you want to do here. If it's an array and you know the size you probably want to return it as an array in Java presumably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case you can [rename `SWIGTYPE_p_...` using an empty definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189929/remove-swigtype-from-generated-class-name) to get it wrapped as an opaque "handle".

This specific instance looks like you've got one of the standard typedefs. You can still do as in the linked answer, e.g.:

```
%module test

%{
#include <stdint.h>
%}

typedef struct {
} uint8_t;

%inline %{
  uint8_t *getData() {
    static uint8_t d[5];
    return d;
  }
%}
```

Which loses the SWIGTYPE_ prefix and can be used as:

```
public class run {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
    test.getData();
  }
}
```

However that's not ideal:

1. There's no access to the array being returned (you probably want to access that data in Java rather than just pass it around)
2. More seriously it will interfere with any other arrays you have  in the same interface and possibly even with string handling

A better solution might be to use the SWIG carrays.i interface to wrap it and use an unbounded array class to exactly replicate the behaviour you would have in C++:

```
%module test

%{
#include <stdint.h>
%}

%include <stdint.i>
%include <carrays.i>

%array_class(uint8_t, U8_Array);

%typemap(jstype) uint8_t *getData "U8_Array"
%typemap(javaout) uint8_t *getData {
  return new $typemap(jstype,uint8_t *getData)($jnicall,$owner);
}

%inline %{
  uint8_t *getData() {
    static uint8_t d[5];
    return d;
  }
%}
```

Your return type will now come from [carrays.i](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Library.html#Library_carrays) and have a `getitem` and `setitem` method.

You can actually use the `jstype` and `javaout` typemaps to map the result (the pointer cast to a `long`) onto *any* Java type, it doesn't have to come from carrays.i just that happens to be quite a useful case. Or you could write come JNI code that returns it as a Java array directly if you're so inclined.

If you know *a priori* the size of the array you can take steps to wrap it as a bounded instead of unbounded array in Java, e.g. [by implementing `AbstractList`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8190135/168175).