# Renaming a SWIGTYPE and injecting code to the generated class

Tags: java, c++, swig

I'm extending jCAE/occjava that is used to access the OpenCasCade C++ library from Java using SWIG generated interface.

Some of the C++ side objects need to be compared for equality i.e. operator `==`.

Specifically instances of class `Handle_Standard_Type`  which are used like in the library to represent dynamic type information using singletons i.e. more or less like enumerations. Don't think that is relevant, just put it here as a background information.

I can make this work with following SWIG definition

```
%typemap(javacode) Handle_Standard_Type& %{
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      boolean equal = false;
      if (obj instanceof $javaclassname)
         equal = ((($javaclassname)obj).swigCPtr == this.swigCPtr);
      return equal;
      }
   %}
```

However this generates an ugly class name `SWIGTYPE_p_Handle_Standard_Type`.

I tried everything I've been able to find, for example this:

[Remove SWIGTYPE from Generated Class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189929/remove-swigtype-from-generated-class-name)

But if I do as suggest and add to my SWIG defs:

```
class Handle_Standard_Type {}
```

The I do get rid of the ugly name but the `equals()` method does not get injected into the Java class.

A further complication is that most of the classes in OCC are accessed using
handles so for each C++ class `Example` there is a `Handle_Example` class.
To get rid of that ugliness on the Java side the occjava project SWIG definitions have a lot of definitions like:

```
%rename(Example) Handle_Example;
```

So I need my solution to follow this naming convention and thus instead of `Handle_Standard_Type` the final generated Java class needs to be named `Standard_Type`.

Here are some more details in case they are relevant or could affect the path taken.

Here is an example of how the dynamic type in OCC works or more precisely how it is accessed from Java using SWIG.

In SWIG we have a definition like this:

```
%{
#include <Geom_Geometry.hxx>
#include <Geom_Plane.hxx>
%}

%rename(Geom_Geometry) Handle_Geom_Geometry;
%rename(Geom_Plane) Handle_Geom_Plane;

%extend Handle_Geom_Geometry {
const Handle_Standard_Type& DynamicType() 
   {
      return (*self)->DynamicType();
   }   
}

class Handle_Geom_Plane: public Handle_Geom_Geometry
{
   Handle_Geom_Plane()=0;
};

%extend Handle_Geom_Plane {
   static const Handle_Standard_Type& STANDARD_TYPE() 
   {
   return STANDARD_TYPE(Geom_Plane);
   }   
}
```

In above `(*self)->DynamicType()` and `STANDARD_TYPE(Geom_Plane)` return a singleton that represents the type of the class in question. A lot of macro magic is used in there.

I'm showing these details because I'm not sure my typemap definition that is inteded to match the `Handle_Standard_Type&` is at all the right way to go about this and I'm open suggestions on how to best handle this.

The bottom line is that on the C++ side I need to access the values returned by the `STANDARD_TYPE()` macro and function `DynamicType` and compare them on the Java side with `equals()` for semantic equivalent of C `==`.

Like this

```
Geom_Surface aSurface = ....
if (aSurface.DynamicType().equals(Geom_Plane.STANDARD_TYPE())) {
   ....
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this with help from "swig-user@lists.sourceforge.net" -list.

The issue is that the class definition needs to come after the
typemap definition.

I incorrectly assumed that the class def needs to be before the typemap
because typically in a programming language you introduce types before you
use them, but of course here it works the other way round because it is
the scope of the typemap that matters, as explained in SWIG Users Manual "10.2.2 Typemap scope":

"Once defined, a typemap remains in effect for all of the declarations that follow."

Below is SWIG definition that worked for me:

```
%rename(Standard_Type) Handle_Standard_Type;
%typemap(javacode) Handle_Standard_Type %{  
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    boolean equal = false;
    if (obj instanceof $javaclassname)
      equal = ((($javaclassname)obj).swigCPtr == this.swigCPtr);
    return equal;
    }
%} 
class Handle_Standard_Type {};
```

In Java one should also remember to override `hashCode()` whenever one overrides `equals()`, so that remains to be done, but that above should answer all my concerns in my original question.